# Can't return CountryDetailsFragment object

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is MyFragmentPagerAdapter class which extends FragmentPagerAdapter.Error is found while returning myFragment

```
public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

final int PAGE_COUNT = 11;


public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {

    CountryDetailsFragment myFragment = new CountryDetailsFragment();
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    data.putInt("current_page", arg0+1);
    myFragment.setArguments(data);
    return myFragment;<----error is shown here.
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return PAGE_COUNT;
}
```

My CountryDetailsFragment is as follows.It extends Fragment and I have populated 2 textviews into a view pager as follows.

```
 public class CountryDetailsFragment extends Fragment{
int mCurrentPage;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /** Getting the arguments to the Bundle object */
    Bundle data = getArguments();

    /** Getting integer data of the key current_page from the bundle */
    mCurrentPage = data.getInt("current_page", 0);

}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.country_details_fragment_layout, null);

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);


    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager(); <---Here the error is shown for getSupportFragmentManager()


    MyFragmentPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(fm);
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.country_details);      
    TextView details = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.country_details_more);


    Bundle b = getArguments();


    tv.setText("Details of " + Country.name[b.getInt("position")]);
    details.setText(Country.details[b.getInt("position")]);

    return v;
}
```

Stacktrace is as follows

03-03 05:15:31.093: E/AndroidRuntime(910): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 05:15:31.093: E/AndroidRuntime(910): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.simplelistdetail.CountryDetailsActivity (has extras) }
03-03 05:15:31.093: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
03-03 05:15:31.093: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
03-03 05:15:31.093: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3390)
03-03 05:15:31.093: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
03-03 05:15:31.093: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3587)
03-03 05:15:31.093: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3555)
03-03 05:15:31.093: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at com.example.simplelistdetail.MainActivity.onListFragmentItemClick(MainActivity.java:62)
03-03 05:15:31.093: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at com.example.simplelistdetail.CountryListFragment.onListItemClick(CountryListFragment.java:48)
03-03 05:15:31.093: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:160)
03-03 05:15:31.093: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
03-03 05:15:31.093: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
03-03 05:15:31.093: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2788)
03-03 05:15:31.093: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3463)
03-03 05:15:31.093: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
03-03 05:15:31.093: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-03 05:15:31.093: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-03 05:15:31.093: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-03 05:15:31.093: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 05:15:31.093: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-03 05:15:31.093: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-03 05:15:31.093: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-03 05:15:31.093: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-03 05:15:33.582: I/Process(910): Sending signal. PID: 910 SIG: 9

Answer (score 0):

if your `CountryDetailsFragment` extends `Fragment` the issue should not exits. Still it could be the case that you are mixing import from the `framework` and the `support library`. Check that all the imports are consistent, either on of

```
android.support.v4.Fragment
```

or

```
android.app.Fragment
```

Comment: I just posted my CountryDetailsFragment.Please see that also.